# Odata query in CRM 2011 that doesn't work

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata, crm

do you have any idea, why this query is not working? it just throws a 400 error

```
http://localhost:5555/CRM11DEV/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=*&$filter=AccountId eq guid'7b45278BE3-4C77-E111-991A-000C2906D485'
```

Every other query with filters that I do work find, only when I try to get an entity by its id like in this example, I get the error

Thanks

Comment: Does the normal id syntax work for that GUID? I.E., ...AccountSet(guid'...')?

Answer (score 2):

Your GUID is too long - looks like you cut and paste it from the URL in the browser - should be 32 characters (minus the dashes) yours is 34. Drop the '7b' at the beginning and it should work just fine.

Comment: +1, Correct. @Jason - may want to add to your answer that 7b is "{" encoded, and 7d is "}" encoded. Knowing that should make it easier to spot in general.